# Fatal exception : AsyncTask #1

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to use a AsynTask to parse XML data.
So in the Activity i've :

```
static List<String> citations = null;

    static void setCitations(List<String> data) {
        citations = data;
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      new data().execute();
```

And in the data class i've :

```
class data extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

    private XMLReader saxReader;
    private SimpleContentHandler simpleContentHandler;

    private List<String> citations;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(List<String> citations) {
        GuiguiActivity.setCitations(citations);
    }


    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
              citations.add("TEST 1");citations.add("TEST 2");
              return citations;
         }   
}
```

Instead of the citations.add i've my XML parser, but even in this case with citations.add errors occur.

```
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at guigui.first.project.data.doInBackground(data.java:82)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at guigui.first.project.data.doInBackground(data.java:1)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-24 15:28:46.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

I don't see where the problem is.

Thanks :)

Comment: There is another problem now.
In the doInBackground i'm getting the XML data.
So I've to send this data to the view.
At the beginning I have 

`setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, MyArrayOfCitations));`

And MyArrayOfCitations was something like that : `String[] = new String[] {"A","B"};`
And now MyArrayOfCitations must be replace by a List<String>
But how do I do if the data retrieving XML start after the displaying of the UI ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't initialize `citations` field. Add a constructor to your `data` class like this:

```
public data(){
    citations = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you AsyncTask you need to initialize your citations field like this:

```
class data extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

private XMLReader saxReader;
private SimpleContentHandler simpleContentHandler;

//I chose and array list here as a concrete implmentation. But you could use any other
//class that also implements the List interface if you want to.
private List<String> citations = new ArrayList<String>();



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(List<String> citations) {
    GuiguiActivity.setCitations(citations);
}


@Override
protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
          citations.add("TEST 1");citations.add("TEST 2");
          return citations;
     }   
}
```

Two other things:

1. Standard convention in java says that class names should always begin with a capital letter. Consider change your AsyncTask class name to something like DataTask, which is both convention compliant and more specific as to what the class does.
2. You've got a lot of variables all with similar names. You should try and flush out what each one actually means and give all your variables more meaninful names. This will help prevent further confusion.

Comment: Thanks, I know my code isn't really clear.
For now I'm learning the android developpement, so when my first objective will be reach i will write another code cleaner
But thx for the 2 points, I will take note for the readability of my code.